# Prevent website from loading in WebView and open in browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, webview

When my website shared in Facebook messenger and such apps, it opens into a WebView.

My questions are:

Is there a way to force it to open in browser instead of the WebView?

As I see `target="_blank"` urls also loaded into WebView, is there a way to leave the WebView with hyperlink or JavaScript?

Comment: Is this WebView implemented by you or 3rd pary app's WebView?

Comment: Third party. For example Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the `UserAgent` string on your server, to  decide whether you should load the website or reject the request. You can refer to this [SO](http://Mozilla/5.0%20(Linux;%20U;%20Android%202.2.1;%20en-us;%20Nexus%20One%20Build/FRG83)%20AppleWebKit/533.1%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Version/4.0%20Mobile%20Safari/533.1) to get insight of the `UserAgent` for `Webview`. However, app can easily by pass this check by setting the `UserAgent`String in `Webview`. This approach atleast helps you to black list some of the Webviews.

To conclude, there is no guaranteed way with which you can control whether Website will be loaded by WebBrowser or Webview.

Comment: Yes, I was able to know whether it is WebView or not. I need to use Google oauth sso on my site, but Google does not allow to use it in WebView. So there only option was to leave the WebView somehow, but it seems like there is not way.

This problem is serious when your website shared in Facebook Messenger with a friend and he is unable to log in with Google while it loaded in WebView...

Comment: Yeah. Google has blocked usage of Webview  for its authentication. But I think if you change the UserAgent of Webview, you should be able to login. You can try it by yourself. If it works that way, then the solution would be to just blacklist the `UserAgent`

Comment: But the app is third party, so I can not change the UserAgent :)

Comment: What I meant was, create your own app with WebView and change its UserAgent. Test if your website works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't! why don't you built a custom script to manually detect whether web page is loaded into webView?
you can do following 2 things
if ur site is loaded into webView you can prompt `"target='_blank'"` to the user or manually request external browser to load that page.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.facebook.orca")
echo 'var isWebView=true;';
else
echo 'var isWebView=false;';
```